# Is union of matrices of different ranks a submanifold?

Tags: matrices, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, matrix-rank, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a **real** $d$-dimensional vector space ($d>2$). Let $1 \le r_1 <r_2 < \dots < r_k = d$ be a fixed finite sequence of numbers.

Define $H=\cup_{i=1}^kH_{r_i}$, where $H_{r}=\{ A \in \text{End}(V) \mid \operatorname{rank}(A) = r 
\}$.

> Is $H$ an embedded submanifold of $\text{End}(V)$?

I know that each $H_{r_i}$ is a connected embedded submanifold of $ \text{End}(V)$, and that $H$ is also connected. (We can "fall in the rank" via a continuous path).

**Note that I do not assume that $r_{i+1}=r_i+1$**. In other words, I am allowing "jumps" of size greater than $1$ between ranks.

(The case where the ranks do jump in $1$ every time is easy; $H$ is just the space of matrices with rank bigger than or equal to $r_1$, which is an open set inside the vector space of all matrices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is false. Consider for example $r_1=1$ and $r_2=d$. Then a matrix $A\in H_d$ is invertible, and all matrices close by as well. Hence if $H_1\cup H_d$ is a submanifold, it is a submanifold of codimension zero. That is $H_1\cup H_d$ is an open subset of all matrices.

This is not the case: We can perturb the matrix $\mathrm{diag}\,(1,0,\ldots,0)\in H_1$ to lie outside $H_1\cup H_d$, namely $\mathrm{diag}\,(1,\epsilon,0,\ldots,0)\not \in H_1\cup H_d$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to note that you are using here the connectedness of $H_1 \cup H_d$. (A disconnected manifold can have components of different dimensions; a connected manifold has a constant dimension). As mentioned in the question, the connectedness here comes from the fact that we can "fall in the rank" via a continuous path. (without passing through all the ranks in the way).

Comment: That is a good point. Perturbing $\mathrm{diag}\,(1,0,\ldots)$ to $\mathrm{diag}\,(1,\epsilon,\ldots,\epsilon)$ shows that you can walk from $H_1$ to $H_d$.